# calculate the difference between two utc time and get the difference in minutes

Tags: javascript, utc

I have two UTC strings, and I want to calculate their difference using javascript.

```
const stored = "2021-09-21T06:49:15.574Z"
const now = "2021-09-21T07:49:15.574Z"
```

I want the output to be in minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried ? what errors are you getting with your current approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please view https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date for more on how to use dates.

```js
// from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

// Using Date objects
let start = Date.now() - 3.6e+6;

// The event to time goes here:
let end = Date.now();
let elapsed = end - start; // elapsed time in milliseconds

let minutes = Math.floor(elapsed / 60000);

console.log(minutes);
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert both to (millisecond) epoch time using [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) and then perform division to get the number of minutes:

```js
const stored = "2021-09-21T06:49:15.574Z";
const now = "2021-09-21T07:49:15.574Z";

const minutes = (new Date(now).getTime() - new Date(stored).getTime()) / 1000 / 60;

console.log(Math.floor(minutes));
```

If you prefer to rely on the fact that `Date` objects get automatically converted to epoch time when used as operands in a mathematical expression, you can even omit the calls to `getTime()`:

```js
const stored = "2021-09-21T06:49:15.574Z";
const now = "2021-09-21T07:49:15.574Z";

const minutes = (new Date(now) - new Date(stored)) / 1000 / 60;

console.log(Math.floor(minutes));
```

Comment: Thanks its working

Answer (score 1):

```js
const stored = "2021-09-21T06:49:15.574Z";
const now = "2021-09-21T07:49:15.574Z";

const minutes = (new Date(now) - new Date(stored)) / 60000;

console.log("minutes difference is : " + Math.floor(minutes));
```